# Bind parameters must be array if namedPlaceHolder parameter is not enabled error

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, next.js

I'm reworking my question as I completely redesigned my API because of a key issue. The fact I have a "file" and it's a multipart/form-data, I needed a form handler since NextJS doesn't have one. So I worked it around "multiparty", where I can actually parse the multipart/form-data coming in from the form. This is the API I use now:

```
import mysql from "mysql2/promise";
import multiparty from "multiparty";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const dbconnection = await mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      database: "onlinestore",
      port: 3306,
      user: "root",
      password: "Jennister123!",
  });
  try {
    const form = new multiparty.Form()

    const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
        if (err) reject({ err })
        resolve({ fields, files })
      })
    })
const query = `INSERT INTO games (ProductID, ProductName, ProductDescription, ProductImage, ProductPrice, DateWhenAdded) VALUES ("${data.fields.ProductID}", "${data.fields.ProductName}","${data.fields.ProductDescription}","${data.fields.ProductImage}","${data.fields.ProductPrice}","${data.fields.DateWhenAdded}")`
    await dbconnection.execute(query, data);
   
    dbconnection.end();
    
    
    data.forEach((games) => {
        games.ProductImage = "data:image/webp;base64," + games.ProductImage.toString('base64');
    }
    );
    data.forEach((games) => {
        var d = new Date(games.DateWhenAdded);
        var now = moment(d).format('l');
        console.log(now);
    }
    );
    res.status(200).json({ games: data });
    

} catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
}
}
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  }
}
```

And obviously from another question, this is the form I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<title>
New Game Addition
</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="/api/newgame" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="number" id = "ProductID" name="ProductID" placeholder="Product ID"> <br />
    <input type="text" id = "ProductName" name="ProductName" placeholder="Name of Product."> <br />
    <input type="text" id = "ProductDescription" name="ProductDescription" placeholder="Describe the Product."> <br />
    <input type="file" id = "ProductImage" name="ProductImage" placeholder="Put in Image"> <br />
    <input type="number" step="0.01" id = "ProductPrice" name="ProductPrice" placeholder="0.00"> <br />
    <input type="date" id = "DateWhenAdded" name="DateWhenAdded" placeholder="01/01/2001"> <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I have a problem to where I get this error on my browser.

```
{"error":"Bind parameters must be array if namedPlaceholders parameter is not enabled"}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error so I can get my query to run?

Comment: When I do a console log of “data.fields.ProductID” however, it pops out [ ‘4’ ]. Hence the individual elements are working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it with this code.

```
import mysql from "mysql2/promise";
import multiparty from "multiparty";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const dbconnection = await mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      database: "onlinestore",
      port: 3306,
      user: "root",
      password: "Jennister123!",
  });
  try {
    const form = new multiparty.Form()

    const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
        if (err) reject({ err })
        resolve({ fields, files })
      })
    })
    const query = "INSERT INTO games (ProductID, ProductName, ProductDescription, ProductImage, ProductPrice, DateWhenAdded) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    const values=[parseInt(data.fields.ProductID), data.fields.ProductName[0], data.fields.ProductDescription[0], data.files.ProductImage[0].toString('base64'), parseFloat(data.fields.ProductPrice), data.fields.DateWhenAdded[0]]

    await dbconnection.execute(query, values);
   
    dbconnection.end();

    res.status(200).json({ games: data });
    

} catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
}
}
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  }
}
```

This code will help me in the end with at least getting everything uploaded and I even tested with my own computer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).